# open material datepicker with button

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to open the material calendar with a fa-icon. So I have it like this:

```
  <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="start" class="editor-label col-sm-4"><strong> Time start:</strong></label>
                <input [(ngModel)]="start" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                 type="text" class="date" id="start" value="start">                
                <span class="ml-2" (click)= "reOpenCalender()">
                    <fa-icon [icon]="faCalendarAlt" size="1x"  #picker [styles]="{'color': '#B7B7B7'}"
                      ></fa-icon>
                </span>
            </div>
```

And ts script like this:

```
reOpenCalender() {
    let self = this;
    setTimeout(() => {
      self.picker.open();
    }, 50);
  }
```

But I get this error:

```
core.js:4442 ERROR TypeError: self.picker.open is not a function
    at widget-editor.component.ts:65
```

if I click on the icon.

So what I have to change?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add `#picker` to icon, icon does not have the open method.
After click on icon you need to call open method on datepicker itself.
You should have something like this:

```
  <span class="ml-2" (click)= "reOpenCalender()">
   <fa-icon [icon]="faCalendarAlt" size="1x"></fa-icon>
  </span>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
```

Please check the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) for more info.